# For every continuous function $h: X \to \mathbb{R}$, the restriction of $h$ to $C$ attains a maximum on $C$. Prove that $C$ is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, solution-verification, compactness

$\mathbf{Question: }\ $ Let $C$ be a subset of a compact metric space $(X,d)$. Assume that for every continuous function $h: X \to \mathbb{R}$, the restriction of $h$ to $C$ attains a maximum on $C$. Prove that $C$ is compact.

$\mathbf{Attempt}: \ $ Suppose, $C$ is a non-empty proper subset of $X$. We pick an arbitrary convergent sequence $\{x_n\} \subset C$, which converges to the limit $l \in X$. We attempt to show that $l \in C$.

We start by assuming the contrary, i.e. $l \notin C$.

Consider $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) \equiv - d(x,l)$, which is a continuous function. Restriction of $f$ on $C$ is denoted by $f_C$ and $-d_C(x,l)$.

By hypothesis, $f_C$ attaints a maximum on $C$, say $M$ at $\xi \in C$; i.e. $f_C(x) \leq M$ $\ \forall x \in C$. Now, all the nonzero values of $f_C$ are negative, and the maximum possible value is $0$. However, if $M=0$, it comes in as a direct contradiction to our initial assumption. Therefore, $M \neq 0$ and $M <0$.

Now, $\forall \varepsilon >0$, $\exists m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $0\leq d(x_n,l)<\varepsilon$, $\forall n\geq m$ $\implies -\varepsilon<-d(x_n,l)\leq0$, $\forall n \geq m$.

We choose $\varepsilon=-\displaystyle\frac{M}{2}>0$.

Now, for $\varepsilon=-\displaystyle\frac{M}{2}>0$, we get an $m_0 \in \mathbb{N}$, such that

$\displaystyle M<\frac{M}{2}<-d(x_n,l)=-d_C(x_n,l)=f_C(x_n)\leq0$, $\forall n\geq m_0$ [Here $d(x_n,l)=d_C(x_n,l)$ since $x_n \in C$, $\forall n$.], which contradicts the fact that $M$ is the attained maximum of $f_C$ on $C$.

Now, abiding by the hypothesis, $f_C$ must "attain" a maximum on $C$ and by our previous arguments, no non zero $M$ can be attained by $f_C$. Thereby, $\displaystyle\max_{x \in C} f_C(x)=0$, which in turn proves that $l \in C$, since $X$ is a metric space.

All the above argument shows that $C$ is closed in the compact metric space $(X,d)$. Therefore $C$ is a compact subset of $X$.

Is the procedure correct?

Kindly $\mathbf{VERIFY}$.

Comment: You should drop that hideous $d_C(x, l)$ notation, it only makes things more confusing (and $f_C$ is clear enough).

Comment: The proof is correct and thorough, well done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct and neatly get around the difficulty imposed by requiring $f$ to be continuous on all of $X$. The natural temptation is to let $f(x)=\frac1{d(x,\ell)}$ and show that $f_C$ is unbounded, but of course that function is undefined at $\ell$. (At any rate it’s the natural temptation if one is familiar with the usual proof that if every continuous real-valued function on a metric space is bounded, the space is compact, which is what I had in mind when I wrote my original answer!) With a little modification that idea can be made to work in essentially the same way that yours does: let $f(x)=\frac1{1+d(x,\ell)}$, so that $f_C(x_n)$ approaches but does not reach $1$. But your approach is simpler.

Comment: Wait, what is $f(l)$ then? $f$ needs to have domain $X$. I suggest to use 
$f : x \to \frac{1}{1 + d(x, l)}$ instead (this function tends to 1 as $x$ tends to $l$, of course).

Comment: @OlivierRoche: You’re right; I was thinking of the more usual result in which $C$ is actually the ambient space. I’ll adjust the answer accordingly.

Comment: I suggest to use 
$f : x \mapsto \frac{1}{1 + d(x, l)}$ instead (this function tends to 1 as $x$ tends to $l$, of course).